# Which country has the most friendly regulatory environment?

Tags: regulation

There has been a lot of discussion of the most oppressive jurisdictions. Which countries have taken notice of these failures and have set up the best regulatory environment to attract Bitcoin related investment rather than chase business away?

Comment: I think this will be very subjective - one country might be more restrictive in some aspects and less restrictive in others.  It requires a value judgment to decide which is "best".  So I think this is too much of an "opinion based" question for this site.  Anyway, there's some bias inherent in your question - what some people call "best regulatory environment" is what others might call "haven for cyber-criminals".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great Britian is a country that many companies moved their bitcoin related business to. One of the the best countries that respect privacy is Switzerland.

There are some tax-heaven type countries that have pro-bitcoin policies.

If you count it toward country Liberland is probably most friendly.

In [this](https://news.bitcoin.com/worlds-top-10-bitcoin-friendly-countries/) article you can find various contries with an explanation.